# How to show zero values for those with count in other months of line chart and don't show for those 0 at all months in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, linegraph

As shown here in the image the categories that doesn't have value shows the category in the line chart where in it should only show those with values greater than 0, and show 0 values for categories with values that is greater than 1 for example comp1 has values for 2 months the other months will show 0 but for comp 6-10 since it doesn't have value in the other months it should not show:

can this be done in power bi
[Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTK9J.png)
This is a sample of the desired result
[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPs8P.png)

I tried using this:
CountComp =
VAR _cnt = CALCULATE(COUNT(Main_Table[Components]), (Main_Table[Row_Number_Comp] = 1))
RETURN
IF(_cnt=0,0,_cnt)

but this shows all values for the other components that is all zero for the other months as well. I need to only show zero values for those with values greater than 0 in the months shown in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your dax to this:

```
Count_Components =
VAR _cnt =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Main_Table[Components] ),
        ( Main_Table[Row_Number_Comp] = 1 )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE( _cnt, _cnt ) * _cnt
```

Using the above DAX, I was able to replicate what you require:

[image: Result]

Is this not what you require?

Comment: Hi @Birel this does not connect the line to the other months and it should also connect to the zero values

Comment: Please edit your question, showing (by adding screenshots) what your current results looks like and what your expected result should look like (also by adding screenshots)

Comment: Hi I've added the screenshots

Comment: @Val, please share a link to your dataset if possible?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-oFar5teQIpL9WkQJv8AjRLLNobL8JEE/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=100957422402184383853&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Lfq2SFfom-1bnGEd8OzqIZNcq41xJB-/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @Val, I updated my answer - is this not what you require?

Comment: Hi, What I wanted is to only show lines for those with values in the months that has value from 2022.08-2023.07, and not show the comp without values example the comp10 has should be 0 for all those months hence it should not be shown in the legend. and in the chart as well. only Comp1-Comp5 should be shown as it has values in the other months